# Is it possible to extract two values with one Dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

With a list comprehension like this, it is possible to extract a specific value from a key in a list of dictionaries:

```
ke = [d['_text'] for d in ls if '_text' in d]
```

Is it possible to extract two values at a time and store them as a tuple with one list comprhension?

So something like this:

```
ke = [(d['_text'] + e['url']) for (d,e) in ls if '_text', 'url' in d,e]
```

EDIT: Excuse me for not posting an example:

```
ls =[{'_text': 'hello', 'url': 'xxx-444.html'}, {'_text': 'bye', 'url': 'xxx-222.html'}]
```

Desire output:

```
ke = [('hello', 'xxx-444.html'), ('bye', 'xxx-222.html')]
```

Comment: That is a _list comprehension_, not a _dictionary comprehension_.

Comment: Try this : 

`ke = [(d.get('_text'), d.get('url')) for d in ls]`

Comment: What about the `if` part? You only want to extract values where *both* keys exist…? Or would it be okay to have `None` in place of missing values?

Comment: @deceze didnt think about this. If one of the keys ```'_text'``` or  ```'url'``` is not there or is ```None``` it should be extracted too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
>>> ls =[{'_text': 'hello', 'url': 'xxx-444.html'}, {'_text': 'bye', 'url': 'xxx-222.html'}]
>>> ke = [(d.get('_text'), d.get('url')) for d in ls]
>>> ke
[('hello', 'xxx-444.html'), ('bye', 'xxx-222.html')]
```

It can handle even if `'_text'` and `'url'` keys are not in any dictionary and in those cases `NoneType` would be added to the tuple. Like for the following case, last dictionary doesn't contain the `'url'` key and `None` is in place of that :

```
>>> ls =[{'_text': 'hello', 'url': 'xxx-444.html'}, {'_text': 'bye', 'url': 'xxx-222.html'}, {'_text' : 'world'}]
>>> ke = [(d.get('_text'), d.get('url')) for d in ls]
>>> ke
[('hello', 'xxx-444.html'), ('bye', 'xxx-222.html'), ('world', None)]
```

Comment: A follow up question, what if I got a second text field in every dictionary like ```'_text2'```.  Could I extract ```_text'``` and  ```'_text2'``` with the same statement to join them? Like ```d.get('_text', '_text2')```?

Comment: @gython No, that `.get()` on dictionary works like `d.get('key_', 'default_val')` i.e. it says look up in the dictionary the value of the key `'key_'` and if can't find then return `'default_value'`. So, you would need `[(d.get('_text', d.get('_text2')), d.get('url')) for d in ls]`. It would check first if `'_text'` key is  there, get that value if not found then get the value for the key `'_text2'`.

Comment: So it's not possible to get ```_text``` and ```_text2``` joined in one statement? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It's not like you can't join them. Try this `[(d.get('_text','')+ d.get('_text2',''), d.get('url')) for d in ls]` with `ls = [{'_text': 'hello'}, {'_text2': 'world'}, {'_text': 'test', '_text2': 'success'}]`. It would give : `[('hello', None), ('world', None), ('testsuccess', None)]`. See how the value for both the key `'_text'` and `'_text2'` are conjoined if present in a single dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Sure.

```
ke = [(d['_text'], e['url']) for d in ls for e in ls if '_text' in d and 'url' in e]
```

Although this should conceptually work, please share a verifiable example.

Comment: I think he wants `ke = [(d['_text'], d['url']) for d in ls if '_text' in d and 'url' in d]` tho

Comment: @FatihAkici sorry for not adding an example. Added one to the OP.